# How do you send React Native Push Notifications with Firebase Admin SDK in a Ruby on Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, react-native, firebase-admin

I am trying to implement push notifications in my React Native project and have set up push notifications to work in my iOS app. I want to send notifications from my Ruby on Rails server, i.e. when the user receives a friend request, but Firebase Admin SDK only provides compatibility with Node.js, Java, Python, C#, and Go. **I wrote my server code in Ruby on Rails and would like to call the Firebase Admin SDK from Rails.**

I am trying to follow this React Native Push Notifications with Firebase tutorial: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/server-integration for sending notifications to specific devices using a notification token, but everything is written in Node.js, and I don't know how to navigate implementing the code in Ruby instead.

I have also looked at the **different Ruby helper libraries for REST APIs for Firebase Admin SDK** here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start, but the documentation for those libraries are a bit too cryptic for me to understand.

Ideally, the functionality I want to implement is similar to:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database
  .ref("users/{userID}")
  .onCreate(event => {
    const data = event._data;
    payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "Welcome",
        body: "thank for installed our app",
      },
    };
    admin
      .messaging()
      .sendToDevice(data.notification_token, payload)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Notification sent successfully:", response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Notification sent failed:", error);
      });
  });
```

but this code from https://www.instamobile.io/react-native-tutorials/push-notifications-react-native-firebase/ is unfortunately in Node.js and won't work on my **Ruby on Rails** server.

Comment: Just a suggestion in you only wanted to send push notifications. Try [onesignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs). Integrating onesignal into rails is quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are some REST examples for FCM in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message. You need an authorization library like https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby to authorize your requests. Then figure out how to make REST calls from Ruby. Here's some example code I've used in the past:

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'

authorizer = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
# Add authorization header to the request
some_headers = {}
authorizer.apply!(some_headers)
some_headers.each do |key, value|
    req[key] = value
end

res = http.request(req)
parsed_results = JSON.parse(res.body)
```

Comment: Thanks Hiranya! This is helpful, I will look into the Google Auth Library for Ruby.